# bash execute multiple greps on each line in a file

Tags: bash, file, loops, grep

I want to run 2 different greps sequentially on each line in a file so that it will output the matches in the order that occurred in the input file. I have a simple file called temp.txt that I will use for this example. Contents of this file are:

```
$ cat temp.txt
line1 a
line2 b
line3 c
```

I have the following code which I have simplified by using an echo instead of the first grep.

```
#! /bin/bash

cat temp.txt | while read line
do
  echo $line
  grep b $line
done
```

I thought the output would have been:

```
line1 a
line2 b
line2 b
line2 c
```

But I am getting the following output:

```
$ ./debug.sh
line1 a
grep: line1: No such file or directory
grep: a: No such file or directory
line2 b
grep: line2: No such file or directory
grep: b: No such file or directory
line3 c
grep: line3: No such file or directory
grep: c: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `grep` assumes the argument is a file, use a here string to feed the variable as stdin `grep b <<< "$line"`

Comment: _"I want to run 2 different greps sequentially on each line in a file so that it will output the matches in the order that occurred in the input file"_ By doing so, you will end up have the line written _twice_ if it matches _both_ patterns. Is that intended?

Comment: Calling `grep` on each line of a file will be slow for a large number of lines. Consider using `bash`'s built-in regular expression matching instead, or combining the regular expressions so that you can using a single call to `grep` that reads the entire file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should only run one `grep`, but give it both patterns to look for:

```
grep 'pattern1\|pattern2' file.txt
```

Comment: typo in this as should have a quote instead of the backtick, otherwise does what I want

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line
do
  echo "$line" | grep "b"
done < temp.txt
```

Or instead of `echo "$line" | grep "b"` you can also use:

```
grep "b" <<< "$line"
```

In your case,

```
grep b $line
```

was trying to `grep b` on a file called `$line`, which obviously does not exist.

Note there is no need to `cat` the file and pipe to the `while`: `while read ... done < file` makes it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should look like this

```
#! /bin/bash

cat temp.txt | while read line
do
  echo $line
  grep b <<< "$line"
done
```

to get the output you want. `grep` is expecting input from a file or from `stdin`. Your syntax makes `grep` think it has to open a file. This version makes sure the `$line` is fed to its `stdin`.